# unable to read json objects in php

Tags: php, json, object, foreach, echo

I want to read JSON in php:

```
$productsArr = json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['object'])); //this give me word Array

stripslashes($_GET['object']) //gives me [{"code":"44-3"}] 

echo $productsArr->{'code'}; //gives me nothing
```

I even tried this:

```
foreach($productsArr as $article)
{
 echo $article->code; //nothing is echoing
}
```

How to access the JSON formatted data in a loop?

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: Post `print_r($_GET['object'])`.

Comment: I'm just trying to get a sense of what the JSON you're trying to parse looks like, so as to have a better idea of what's going wrong

Comment: try to use instead of $_GET['object'] this urldecode(@$_REQUEST['object'])

Comment: it looks like `[{\"code\":\"54-LA\"}]`

Comment: The code you have should work. Be sure `$_GET['object']` has what you expect.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary code is not working

Comment: @user123_456 $productsArr[0]->code should work... as well as your foreach example above.

Comment: I think that problem is in this `json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['object'])); `because I had the same code on the local server and it is working there without stripslashes.

Answer (score 0):

1) Force an array to be returned by supplied true to second argument of json_decode.

2) Ensure that this produces an array:

```
$productsArr = json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['object']), true);
print_r($productsArr);
```

Assuming it does. Access your elements as such:

echo $productsArr['foo']['bar'];

Comment: when I use echo I'm getting this: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => 54-LA ) )`

Comment: how to access an element in a foreach loop

Comment: In this case, when you run a foreach against the array, it will access each element on the first level (0-x, in this case only 0.) Ex. foreach($producstArr as $product) echo $product['code']; Without a foreach, you can access it directly via echo $productsArr[0]['code'];